# Formatar data escrita "ex. 12 de Janeiro de 2017" para o padrão (Y-m-d)

Tags: php, data

É possível passar uma data nesse padrão "12 de Janeiro de 2017" para o padrão americano (Y-m-d) ?

Algum exemplo?

Obrigado.

Comment: Você quer transformar uma string em data, ou quer formatar a saída de uma data de verdade?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, quero que a saída seja uma data valida no formato americano para adicionar no banco de dados.

Comment: Mas a entrada é uma data ou uma string? Se for data, um simples date('Y-m-d') basta. E isso NÃO é padrão americano. Aliás, é importante [edit] a pergunta e explicar melhor o que quer, nem todo mundo lê comentários. (na verdade nem todo mundo lê a pergunta direito).

Comment: Observação, issso não é padrão americano. É o padrão ISO 8601 https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ISO_8601&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando a função [date_create_from_format](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date-create-from-format.php) você consegue formatar a data como deseja mas antes deve fazer algumas alterações:

```
$string = "12 de Dezembro de 2017";

$string = preg_replace('/( de ){1,2}/', ' ', $string);

$month = [
        'Janeiro' => 'January',
        'Fevereiro' => 'February',
        'Marco' => 'March',
        'Abril' => 'April',
        'Maio' => 'May',
        'Junho' => 'June',
        'Julho' => 'July',
        'Agosto' => 'August',
        'Novembro' => 'November',
        'Setembro' => 'September',
        'Outubro' => 'October',
        'Dezembro' => 'December'
    ];

$string = str_replace(array_keys($month), array_values($month), $string);

$dr= date_create_from_format('d M Y', $string);
echo $dr->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date('Y-m-d', strtodate($string));
```

Comment: gostaria de saber o motivo da marcação negativa, não fui claro o suficiente ?